# delete an image result in error undefined method `count' for nil:NilClassh Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

When I hit button to delete the image from page, the image gets delete but i have to refresh the page to be able to see it.I'm getting an error from

```
//The command line
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `count' for 
nil:NilClass):
1: <% if @photos.count > 0 %>
2: <br/><br/>
3:
4: <div class="row">
```

model

```
//app/models/item.rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos
  validates :item_category, presence: true
  validates :item_condition, presence: true
end
```

views

```
//app/views/photos/destroy.js.erb
$('#photos').html("<%= j render 'photos_list' %>")
```

Views here im getting the error that count is undfined

```
//app/views/photos/_photos_list.html.erb
<% if @photos.count > 0 %>
<br/><br/>

<div class="row">
  <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading preview">
  <%=  image_tag photo.image.url() %>
        </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="pull-right">
     <%= link_to item_photo_path(photo.item_id, photo), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <% end %>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How is this `@photos` variable set? What's the source of your `destroy` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `@photos` variable is not available in your destroy action.

```
def destroy
  ...
  @photos = Photo.all
  ...
end
```

**Refactoring idea:**

Remove the `div` containing the deleted photo after the photo is deleted. That way you shouldn't reload the whole `div`.

**app/views/photos/destroy.js.erb**

```
$('.photo-<%= @photo.id %>').remove();
```

**app/views/photos/_photos_list.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
    <div class="col-md-4 photo-<%= photo.id %>"> <!-- Dynamic class for photo added -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading preview">
  <%=  image_tag photo.image.url() %>
        </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="pull-right">
     <%= link_to item_photo_path(photo.item_id, photo), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <% end %>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: in my app/controllers/photos_controller.rb I forget to add s to photo now is working .

Answer (score 0):

ok here is the issue:

you need to pass local variable in your partial: -

```
$('#photos').html("<%= j render 'photos_list', photos: @photos %>")
```

and in your partial replace instance variable @photos with local variable photos

```
<% if photos.count > 0 %>
<br/><br/>

<div class="row">
  <% photos.each do |photo| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading preview">
  <%=  image_tag photo.image.url() %>
        </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="pull-right">
     <%= link_to item_photo_path(photo.item_id, photo), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <% end %>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Note: - partial are used to common, behaviour of different actions show its always good practice to pass local variable with partial

and i think your destroy action should like this: -

```
def destroy
  photo = @Photo.find(:id)
   if photo.destroy
    flash[:success] = "photo deleted."
   end
  @photos = Photo.all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in my app/controllers/photos_controller.rb I forget to add s to photo now is working .

```
  def destroy
     @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
     item = @photo.item
     @photo.destroy
     @photos = Photo.where(item_id: item.id)

    respond_to :js
  end
```